# React onClick wont get api request unless clicked twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to tell react, onClick run `process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOUT` and remove the item set in localstorage.

Unfortunately, i have to click it two times, once it clicks the first time, you will get redirected to the index page, and you have to click it again once you are on the index page for it to send the axios get request, is there a way i can make it work all in one click ?

**Navbar**

```
const logout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOUT)) {
        localStorage.removeItem('auth'); // it runs this first
        history.push('/');  // sends to index page, then i have to click it again for it to execute the get request from Axios.
    };

};


     <Button onClick={logout}>
        <Link className={classes.rightToolbar} to={'/logout'}>
            LogOut
        </Link>
    </Button>
```

Comment: A bit hard without a working example, but did you try to remove <Link>, maybe something in there is also listening to clicks.

Comment: @randal Are you sure you need to use `Axios.get()` to get the environment variable? Maybe you can just use `process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOUT` directly.

Comment: yes i needed to use axios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger the `history.push` after API success. You can make use of async await for it

```
const logout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const res = await Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOUT)
        if(res) {
            localStorage.removeItem('auth'); // it runs this first
            history.push('/');  // sends to index page, then i have to click it again for it to execute the get request from Axios.
        };

    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
 <Button onClick={logout}>
    <Link className={classes.rightToolbar} to={'/logout'}>
        LogOut
    </Link>
</Button>
```

Comment: this technically works, but it doesn't redirect  `/` index page. It instead gets sent to logout page. (which really isn't a page) i will accept in 5 minutes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the `Axios.get` promise to resolve.

```
const logout = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOUT)
    .then(res => {
      if (res) {
        localStorage.removeItem('auth')
        history.push('/')
      }
     }).catch(err => {
       // didnt work
     })
 }

<Button className={classes.rightToolbar} onClick={logout}>
  LogOut
</Button>
```

Comment: seems overengineered to make logout an async function in my opinion.